# REST API Pagination in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a project scenario to get all values from an endpoint URL. I am using ADF Pipeline but I'm having some issues with pagination.

To get the following values, I need to make requests with the PaginationCursor value in the current body response in the following request header.

I have read that ADF supports the following case, which would be mine.
Next request’s header = property value in current response body [ADF - Pagination support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support)

I don't know how to use the following attributes in order to use the paginationCursor value from the current response body in the header of the next request.
[Attributes for pagination in ADF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqLcY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem with the following attributes.

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx86t.png)

In the Headers I had to put the name of the header of the next call. In my case the name is PaginationCursor and I got the value of this header from the actual body response called paginationCursor.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce above but not successful. Instead, if you want to do it without pagination, you can try this approach.

First create a **web activity** with any page URL of your API to get the **total number of pages count**.
In ForEach create an array for page numbers using the count from web activity as

```
@range(1,activity('Web1').output.total_pages)
```

Inside ForEach use the **copy activity** and give the source REST dataset parameter for the page number like `?page=@{item()}`.

In the sink dataset also, create a dataset for each page with the dataset parameter value like `APIdataset@{item()}.csv`. This generates the sink dataset names like APIdataset1.csv, APIdataset2.csv,...

Now, you can copy from your REST API without pagination.

**My repro for your reference:**


[image]


**Copy activity:**


[image]

Comment: This answer should contain some information how this changes runtime and cost of the pipeline. On our use case loop construct has 60x runtime and 90x cost increase.